# How to put an UIWebView inside UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've tried to add a `WebView` to the `AlertView` using this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
search = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"iGoogle" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Search", nil];
[search addSubview:googleView];
googleView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[search show];

[search release];

[super viewDidLoad]; }
```

Still, only the AlertView shows up, without the WebView. And also, where can I get more details on adding stuff like CGRectMakes?

Comment: Can you check out this post here? http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1704-uitextfield-inside-uialertview.html#post10643

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to add `[search addSubview:googleView];` after the googlview is allocated...

Comment: Haha, nice notice.. we all overlooked that :)

Comment: @richard: SO doesnt have anything to send personal message :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to interchange `addSubview:googleView` call string with `googleView =` string?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to something I used a while back to add a subview to a UIAlertView. The "trick" is adding a message param that makes the alert view increase in height, then you place a subview on top of that. I've never tried it with a web view.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1704-uitextfield-inside-uialertview.html

Also make your you init your webview with a url and implement delegate as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
googleView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];

search = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"iGoogle" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Search", nil];

[search addSubview:googleView];

[search show];

[search release];

[super viewDidLoad]; 

}
```

Initialize the memory for the webview first and then add it inside the alert view.

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8.

To get the same thing implemented use `UIAlertController`.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"page" withExtension:@"html"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];  
[webView loadRequest:request];

UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"HTML" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[alert.view addSubview:webView];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: When I try this, my webview sits on top of the alert rather than as part of it.